# setHeader does not change file name

Tags: java, playframework, hbase

When I use a variable for filename to set name of downloaded file, it does not see the variable. But if I do not use a variable for filename, then it sets the name as I want.

`response().setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=testName.pdf");` with this way,  name of downloaded file is testName.pdf

I tried three different ways to use it with a variable.

`response().setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename="+ fileName.toString() +".pdf");`

or

```
..... "attachment; filename="+ fileName +".pdf");
```

or

```
..... "attachment; filename="+ fileName.toString() +".pdf");
```

Full code:

```
public static Result download(String id) throws IOException {
        Get g = new Get(Bytes.toBytes(id));
        g.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("content"), Bytes.toBytes("raw"));
        g.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("book"), Bytes.toBytes("title"));

        HTable hTable = new HTable(hConn.config, "books");
        org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result result = hTable.get(g);

        if (result.containsColumn(Bytes.toBytes("content"), Bytes.toBytes("raw"))){
            byte[] rawBook = result.getNoVersionMap().get(Bytes.toBytes("content")).get(Bytes.toBytes("raw"));
            byte[] fileName = result.getNoVersionMap().get(Bytes.toBytes("book")).get(Bytes.toBytes("title"));
            response().setContentType("application/octet-stream");
            response().setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\".pdf");
            return ok(rawBook);
        }
        return notFound();
    }
```

So, this is from Java Play Framework. Database is HBase. I have one table named `books` and it has two families `content` and `book`. `content` contains content of pdf (in byte), `book` contains some properties of pdf(title, page number, author etc.). `Row Key` for both `content` and `book` is the same.

Is there another way to set filename by using variable, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the problem is in converting the `byte[]` to a `String`. A simple `toString()` on that array will lead to something like `[B@186b085` - which is AFAIK not accepted as a `filename` here.

Try converting the `byte[]` to `String` like this:

```
String fn = new String(filename, "UTF-8");
```

Note that encoding is always important but using this constructor you will have to catch `UnsupportedEncodingException`.

In Java 8 you can use the follwoing, without having to catch `UnsupportedEncodingException`:

```
String fn = new String(filename, java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: Yes you were right. I was getting [B@... Thank you so much.